# Disable PHP mail() function if using SendGrid API

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki, sendgrid

I am using MediaWiki with the [SendGrid Extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SendGrid) but MediaWiki appears to be using PHP `mail()` and/or SMTP i.e. sendmail or postfix MTAs. I've setup MediaWiki to use SendGrid RESTful API. I am not using SMTP.

I receive email from MediaWiki via SendGrid ok, but MediaWiki still displays a PHP mail error.

Answer (score -1):

@TimD,

Not sure on which OS you running your MediaWiki, below possible tips to check if that resolve the issue.

- you can check server mail status by

> getsebool -a | grep mail

This command can give you a response 'on' of 'off'

- well if you see the response as **allow_postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> off** , then try it with following commend to set it on

> setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on

This will set mail options to 'on' in your server OS

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu but MediaWiki should not be using PHP mail i.e. sendmail or postfix MTAs. I've setup MediaWiki to use SendGrid RESTful API — not SMTP

Comment: ok but that mean you will need to remove / commit mail() function from source code,as you don't want to enable the os mail..!

Comment: I'd rather switch to using the SendGrid SMTP relay before hacking up the MW core — this is why we have extensions